# CartThrob Price Modifier Not Adding Price

Tags: cartthrob, price-modifier

I have a CartThrob price modifier being output in an EE template and everything displays fine. The problem is that no matter what, the price modifier isn't doing anything to the actual price of an item.

Here's the template code for the price modifier:

```
{exp:cartthrob:item_options entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"}
{if dynamic}
    <div class="form-item">
        <label>{option_label}</label>{input}
    </div>
{if:else}
    {if options_exist}
        <div class="form-item">
        <label>{option_label}:</label>
        {item_options:select}   
            <option {selected} value="{option_value}"> {option_name}{if price} {price}{/if} </option>
        {/item_options:select}  
        </div>
    {/if}
{/if}
{/exp:cartthrob:item_options}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that in the setup the client had added a dollar sign to their prices. For some reason, CartThrob changes values with $ into 0 so the price update wasn't taking effect.

tldr; ensure the prices within your Price Modifier field are numbers (float, ints, etc) only.

Comment: Oh God, I ran into this issue a few weeks ago and much time passed and hair pulling occurred.